# How to get Entity framework to create/update the Database table without saving an object

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework-4.1

I'm in the process of adding new fields, on my class but I've noticed the table won't be created until I save an object of that class. It's a bit annoying, is there a way to force it to create that table on App start or something?

Comment: I believe the model creation doesn't start unless you touch entity sets. Agree that updating/saving is annoying. I believe entity query also starts model creation which is less annoying then an update or insert. A simply query like `contx.SomeEntityset.FirstOrDefault(<some simple expression>);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can force the initializer at `Application_Start` by

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    Database.SetInitializer(new DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<MyContext>());
    (new MyContext()).Database.Initialize(true);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use Repository and Unit of Work patterns.

[Using Repository and Unit of Work patterns with Entity Framework 4.0](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2009/06/16/using-repository-and-unit-of-work-patterns-with-entity-framework-4-0.aspx)

which the Save method is defined in IUnitOfWork interface.

```
public interface IUnitOfWork
{
    void Save();
}
```